# Logistic regression variance

Tags: self-study, logistic, generalized-linear-model

So far I have checked the tolerance value, VIF and condition indexes. But checking the variance of the regression coefficients I have to wonder: how little variance of the regression coefficient should be associated with the smallest eigenvalue and what is too much (indicating multicollinearity)?

Comment: Eigenvalues of which matrix?